# failed to use mapreduce in python

Tags: python-2.7, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

I am trying to learn mapreduce program using python mrjob. I am getting following error:

Traceback:

```
dumping stdin to local file /tmp/pyes_mrjob.testuser.20131004.103251.998597/STDIN
Making directory hdfs:///user/testuser/tmp/mrjob/pyes_mrjob.user.20131004.103251.998597/files/ on HDFS
> /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/bin/hadoop fs -mkdir hdfs:///user/testuser/tmp/mrjob/pyes_mrjob.testuser.20131004.103251.998597/files/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyes_mrjob.py", line 34, in <module>
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 500, in run
    mr_job.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/job.py", line 518, in execute
    super(MRJob, self).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 146, in execute
    self.run_job()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/launch.py", line 207, in run_job
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/runner.py", line 458, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 236, in _run
    self._upload_local_files_to_hdfs()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 263, in _upload_local_files_to_hdfs
    self._mkdir_on_hdfs(self._upload_mgr.prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/hadoop.py", line 271, in _mkdir_on_hdfs
    self.invoke_hadoop(['fs', '-mkdir', path])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mrjob/fs/hadoop.py", line 81, in invoke_hadoop
    proc = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I executed the command manually its working fine there but when i try to execute my program its not working. 
Since just started learning can someone suggest what library i have to choose. According to some blogs somelibraries has good documention and some libraries has better perfomance and .... I came across below post which looks older
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/01/a-guide-to-python-frameworks-for-hadoop/

But so many libraries got updates recently. So can some suggest me library i can start with..

Comment: Posting code / command which is throwing this error would be useful.

Comment: i am using the mrjob documentation example.

Answer (score 5):

i guess this problem is caused by the way how mrjob calls "hadoop fs -mkdir", if the parent dir of the targeted dir you want to make doesn't exist, -mkdir will fail. that means you have to use "hadoop fs -mkdir -p [path]". Ultimately, you will need to modify mrjob library manually in [path of mrjob install](mine is /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/mrjob)/hadoop.py at line 271:

```
self.invoke_hadoop(['fs', '-mkdir', path])
```

to

```
self.invoke_hadoop(['fs', '-mkdir', '-p', path])
```

Good Luck!

Comment: When will this be fixed? THis is November 2014 and I am still seeing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you set your HADOOP_HOME to "/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce". However, this is wrong and it should be set to "/usr/lib/hadoop".

Also, if you get an error saying that the hadoop-streaming.jar could not be found, create a symlink in "/usr/lib/hadoop" to this jar as follows:

```
    sudo ln -s /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar /usr/lib/hadoop
```